# C++ implicit data sharing

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, c++11

I'm trying to understand the concept of Implicit Data Sharing. After some searches online I found some information but what I'm missing is some simple example of how this is implemented.
I know for a fact that QT is using Implicit Data Sharing in some of its classes.

Does this mean that data is references and not copied to save memory and speed up things?

Any C++ simple example of how this is done?

Comment: Also search the web for "c++ copy on write"

Comment: check [documentation of Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qshareddatapointer.html#details) there is good example how to do it with qt.

Comment: I'm looking for an example without using QT classes. So that I can learn how to implement it myself.